# Updating the history table with delete and insert

Tags: sas

If an id from temp is matched with an id in hist then delete that row from the hist and insert it from temp, and if the id is not matched with any rows in hist then append the row to the hist.
I have two Datasets with the same columns:

```
data hist;
input id1 id2 var1 $;
cards;
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 c 
4 40 d
5 50 e
;
run;
data temp;
input id1 id2 var1 $;
cards;
2 20 b
3 30 d
4 40 e
5 50 f
6 60 g
;
run;
```

`temp` will have current and `history` will have all the history rows.

I want to delete and insert a row in the `history` dataset if it exists in `temp` (Update).. and append a row to the `history` dataset if a row from `temp` does not exists in `history`.
`history` dataset will have at least 100 mill records. From the above inputs I want output like this.

```
1 10 a
2 20 b
3 30 d
4 40 e
5 50 f
6 60 g
```

Rows 1,2,3,4 from `temp` are matched with rows in `history` so they will updated and row 5 from `temp` is not a match so it will be appended to `history` .

Sorry for the confusion before. It should be clear now I guess.
Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Based on your response to one of the comments below, it appears that your `history` dataset is stored in a sequential library (probably using the `V9TAPE` engine). Unless you can move this dataset to a `V9` engine library or similar, you will not be able to use any of the solutions that depend on indexes and direct access methods.

Comment: @user667489 : Thanks for your reply...It is very big table... It can have atleast 100 million records...So, trying to find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to let SAS and PROC APPEND do this for you.

So without knowing your data columns, I will talk in general.  I assume you have 1 or more field(s) that define the uniqueness.

First, create a unique index on HISTORY

```
proc sql;
create unique index hist_unq on HISTORY(col1, col2, ...);
quit;
```

Then use PROC APPEND:

```
proc append base=history data=temp force;
run;
```

You will see a Warning in the log and notice that less than the total were appended.  Something like:

```
NOTE: Appending WORK.TEMP to WORK.HISTORY.
WARNING: Duplicate values not allowed on index hist_unq for file HISTORY, 36 observations rejected.
NOTE: There were 70 observations read from the data set WORK.TEMP.
NOTE: 34 observations added.
NOTE: The data set WORK.HISTORY has 144 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: PROCEDURE APPEND used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I didn't know SAS would just give you a warning in this case, I'd have thought it would error.

Comment: on my machine, appending a few thousand rows (with another few thousand thrown out as dups) to a 1.5G history table takes less than half a second.

Comment: Are you taking index creation time into account?

Comment: (Not that my solution is likely to be faster, in general, I think this is fastest - hash table build is slower than index creation by quite a bit, I think.)

Comment: You can also use the `nowarn` option with `proc append` in conjunction with `force`.   This will also remove the warning message.  I don't normally advocate removing warning messages, but this is one of the exceptions where it's pretty harmless (at least in my experience).  If there are bugs, they are easy to solve.

Comment: The timing of the index creation does not matter.  You only have to create it once.  PROC APPEND maintains the index each time you do the append.  Just don't do anything to delete the index.   @RobertPenridge, good tip on the NOWARN option.

Comment: @RobertPenridge, actually, the NOWARN option does not suppress the WARNING message (9.4 TS1M2 - Windows) on my machine.  &SYSERR is still 4, even with the NOWARN option.

Comment: @DomPazz Hmm, you're right, it's the same for me in 9.3.  I didn't notice it at first because the warning did not appear in the usual green text in the log.  That's very unusual behaviour for SAS as normally any line in the log that starts with `WARNING:` (even if created via a `put` or `%put`) will appear green.

Comment: @DomPazz :Your code is appending the non-matching rows to the history but not updating the history table with matching rows. Thanks for the answer though. It would be great if there is a 'replace' option in Append like in modify statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think DomPazz has the best answer so far, by virtue of its simplicity, but if you are in a situation where you cannot conveniently define a unique index on `history`, or you really want to avoid any warning messages, then the following more complex data step approach works. It should be almost as fast as `proc append` while avoiding the memory and CPU requirements of the hash object approach set out by Joe.

N.B. although this does not require a unique index on `history`, it will append unwanted rows from `temp` if you have more rows for any matching id in `temp` than you do in `history`.

```
data history;
input id var1 $;
cards;
1 a
2 b
3 c 
4 d
5 e
5 f
;
run;

data temp;
input id var1 $;
cards;
3 d
4 e
5 f
6 g
6 h
;
run;

proc datasets lib = work nolist;
    modify history;
    index create id;
    run;
quit;

data history;
    set temp;
    modify history key = id;
    if _iorc_ ne 0 then do;
        _ERROR_ = 0;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

How this works:

1. Read in a record from `temp` (1st set statement)
2. Attempt to read in the first record from `history` with a matching `id` value.
3. If we didn't find a match, output a new record.
4. Because we never read in a row from `history` for any of the non-matching `id`s from `temp`, the values of all the other variables are still present in the PDV from when we read them in from `temp` in step 1.
5. The index for `history` isn't updated until after the data step has finished adding/modifying/removing rows, so for the last row of `temp`, even though we've already added one row with `id = 6` to `history`, we don't find it via the index in subsequent iterations of the same data step, so both rows are added.

Edit: alternative version which updates records in history with matching ids:

```
data history;
    set temp(rename = (var1 = new_var1));
    do _n_ = 1 by 1 until(eof);
        modify history key = id end = eof;
        if _iorc_ = 0 then do;
            var1 = new_var1;
            replace;
        end;
        else do;
            _ERROR_ = 0;
            if not(eof and _n_ > 1) then output;
        end;        
    end;
run;
```

One drawback here is that you have to rename all the non-id variables in `temp`, because when the `modify` statement reads in a row from `history` it overwrites variables with the same names in the PDV. If you have unique indexes on id for both `temp` and `history`, you can avoid this like so:

```
data history;
    set temp(keep = id);
    modify history key = id;
    if _iorc_ = 0 then do;
        set temp key = id;
        replace;
    end;
    else do;
        _ERROR_ = 0;
        output;
    end;        
run;
```

The extra set statement reads in the relevant record from `temp` a second time if a matching record was read in from `history` that overwrote it the first time.

Comment: Not nearly as fast - 5 seconds or so on my machine to do the modify vs 0.2s for append for 1G history/10M temp - but no warnings in the log might be worth it.

Comment: I expect it's the overhead from row-by-row keyed access, which proc append is presumably able to mitigate. I suppose this does potentially save you a data step if you want to do something else at the same time, though.

Comment: Does it actually look at each and every row in `history` (at least, at the index, once for each row)?  That would be a very slow use of the index.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I don't think you need the `if _n_=1 by 1 ` wrapper - just directly modifying it should be fine, no?  Since the ID has to be unique?  (Not that it makes any difference in runtime since the loop only executes one time...)

Comment: You're right - one only needs to read in the first row returned by each key. Answer updated.

Comment: @user667489 : I tested your code, its adding new id values from temp but not updating already existing id's in history.                                                                                                        I'm looking for something which updates a row in the history if the id value is present in both temp and history and add a row to the history if the id value from temp is not present in history. I will dedup the temp dataset before to make sure that I have only 1 row for each id.

Comment: That's certainly possible - I just thought you wanted to leave existing rows unchanged.

Comment: @user667489 : Thanks a lot its working....but my history table is on LASR Analytical server which is throwing follow error.                         ERROR: Update access is not supported for file LASRLIB.DELNINS_HISTORY.DATA.

Comment: Based on the error description [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/3/592.html), it looks as though you will need to store your data elsewhere, in a non-sequential library, or else rebuild the history table completely every time you update it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do what you describe is the `union` in SQL.  `union` by default does not append duplicate records.  It does, however, take some time (as it has to identify those records).

```
proc sql;
  create table history_new as
  select * from history
  union
  select * from temp;
quit;
```

If you have enough memory to load the keys to `history` in a hash table in memory, that is likely the fastest option.  Load `history` to a hash, set temp, `find()` the current row, if it is not found then add that row to the hash.  Then, at the end, output the hash back to History.

Depending on the relative sizes of temp and history, you also could output only the to-be-added rows to a dataset rather than adding them to the hash, then `proc append` that dataset.

If `temp` is less than a quarter or so the size of `history` that's probably the better option.

```
data temp_to_Add;
  set temp;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash h(dataset:'history');
    h.defineKey('keyvars');
    h.defineDone();
  end;
  rc = h.find();
  if rc ne 0 then output;
run;
```

If you need to check `temp` against itself, also add the node to the hash when `rc ne 0`.

Comment: beats me to it, again!  The real issue will be performance as HISTORY grows.

Comment: Right.  I considered actually the reverse - set history, hash temp - but the append solution is probably faster than that I'd think, no? Or can you use `modify` to make this the better option?  (And, would the lookups of every `history` row in a small `temp` table be too expensive?  May be worth it if you have a reasonably easy way to filter out most of `history`, like date boundaries or something.)

Comment: I would use a unique key on HISTORY and PROC APPEND.  I'm not sure what is the fastest way at on a large number of records.

Comment: I've added an answer based on `modify`.